# Was the Monopoly Income Tax ever $150?

Tags: monopoly

According to the «Income Tax» entry in [Monopoly Wiki](https://monopoly.fandom.com/wiki/Income_Tax#Original_1935_Edition),

> In the original 1935 edition, the tax amount was $300; the change to $200 didn't come until a year later.

In the American editions, apart from the added option to pay 10%, was the flat income tax amount ever some other amount, like $150?

I ask this questions because I may buy a vintage handmade board on which the Income Tax square is $150; knowing if this amount was ever used would help me to date the original board.
[image: Income Tax $150]

Comment: Note that the Monopolywiki entry text may be a bit misleading. The 10% option way always there in all editions until the 2008 change. In the original 1935 version, it was "10% or $300". It was changed to "10% or $200".

Answer (score 2):

No. According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopoly_(game)#Board), the only change other than from the original $300 was the elimination of the percentage option altogether in 2008.

(The Wiki entry apparently ignores the original hand-made versions: the circular track version whose "Income Tax" space had no flat fee option at all: just "Pay 10%".)